# [self viewDidAppear:YES];

Tags: iphone, ipad, viewdidload, viewdidappear

Does `[self viewDidAppear:YES];` in the viewDidLoad section of code ensure that the viewDidAppear section of code will run?

Based on feedback from a small subset of our users, it appears for whatever reason that the code I have written in the viewDidAppear section of the main menu's view is not running for them - but it works perfectly well for the majority of users and in all my testing. I'm hoping that by adding [self viewDidAppear:YES]; this will fix the issue for those devices that for some reason were not calling viewDidAppear...

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ViewDidAppear may not be getting called if its on a view controller that is nested in another view controller and running on an older OS. Before iOS 5, delegate commands did not always get forwarded to child controllers.

Comment: I will ask these people if they could tell me which OS they are running... and hopefully everyone will update their devices!

Comment: Got an email reply from one person having this issue that was indeed running 4.3.3 on their iPad 2. Wonder how many users haven't upgraded their OS...

Comment: Based on one user's feedback - this didn't seem to resolve the issue on a pre-iOS 5 device anyways. Several users have now updated their iPads and the issue has been fixed.

Comment: So... any ideas on what's the best workaround? Set a BOOL value to YES in viewDidAppear and then call [self performSelector:@selector(checkIfDidAppear) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0f]; and then run the viewDidAppear code myself if viewDidAppear had not been called and so the BOOL hadn't been set to YES?  Doesn't seem like a great setup... any other ideas?

Comment: In your parent controller's VDA check for iOS5 and if older manually call VDA on your child controllers.

Answer (score 5):

I think that's a horrible idea, personally.  I think you're better off finding out WHY `viewDidAppear` didn't execute for that subset of users.  You may only be treating a symptom of a greater problem by just 'fixing' what appears to be wrong.

Comment: any ideas why a viewDidAppear wouldn't execute?

Comment: I'm adding the view with: UIViewController *nextController = [[MainMenuController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenuController" bundle:nil];
[nextController performSelector:@selector(setDelegate:) withObject:self];
[self.view addSubview:nextController.view];

Answer (score 1):

You should never call delegate methods directly.

Comment: Perhaps you could expand this answer and explain why?